# Subject and object in sentence

Tags: subjects

If I say,

> Event-one is true only if Event-two is true.

In above sentence, which event is subject of the sentence and which event is object of the sentence?

Comment: There is no object. "True" is an adjectival predicative complement of "be", not object. The answer below is wrong about this and needs correcting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of this as two sentences (well, clauses, really), each with its own subject and predicate:

1. Event-one is true

only if

2. Event-two is true.

"If," here, is a [subordinating conjunction](https://convoenglish.co/conjunctions-if-unless-subordinating-conjunctions/). The first clause is *independent*, standing by itself. The second clause *could be* independent, but "only if" makes it subordinate to the first part.

Comment: You say "each with its own subject and object", but there is no object. "Event one" is, of course, subject, but "true" is predicative complement of "be", not object.

Comment: Thanks, @BillJ, typo corrected.